# Algorithm: How to select a subset of fixed size from an original set, such that it maximises an arbitrary metric on all elements contained.

Tags: vectors, algorithms

## Preamble

I have something that has come up at work, and I believe this is a case of "I've seen problems like this before, but in terms of extracting the generic algorithm, I'm not sure what to Google". I am including details and more context below, but I feel like a generic algorithm (if such a thing exists for this problem) must be sticking out somewhere, and would ideally like to know what this is outside of the situation in which I need to use this. Also, as I'm hoping to find a generic algorithm as the solution, I'm posting on the Maths Stack Exchange, but I'm not a great mathematician so please bear with me on that. This might belong more on the Theoretical CS site, but it seems borderline to me and that site has fewer members so I wasn't sure I'd get as good a variety of responses. Ultimately the aim is for a solution in code which is really my background.

## Generic Problem

Let's say I have an original set $O$, consisting of $n_o$ items. I have some binary function $f$ that is defined over the Cartesian product of all the elements of $O$, and as such, returns some "metric" between any two elements in $O$. My question is,

> Given a fixed number of elements $n_s$, how can I choose a subset $S$ of this size, from the elements of $O$, such that I maximise the total value of $f$ across all the elements in $S$.

*Please see below for my reservations of if I have defined this correctly; I would happily update the question if it would be better posed in another way*

My friend, who's more of a pure mathematician than I am, suggested that this might nbe a more intuitive way to express for a mathematician:

> Let $O$ be a finite metric space with metric $f$.
>
> For a given $n_s \le \lvert O \rvert$, find $S \subseteq O$ such that:
>
> - $\lvert S \rvert = n_s$
> - $\forall S' \subseteq O$ with $\lvert S'\rvert = n_s$:
>
>   $min\{f(s_1, s_2) : s_1 \neq s_2; s_1, s_2 \in S\} \geq   min\{f(s_1, s_2) : s_1 \neq s_2; s_1, s_2 \in S'\} $

---

This problem feels like many similar problems and I'm sure I've encountered several situations like this before, e.g.:

- Minimal Spanning Trees
- Principal Component Analysis
- Travelling Salesman

However, in these cases,

- usually the process of calculating the metric and then building the subset are occurring simultaneously; I'd like to know if there exists a generalised decoupled form of algorithm that purely selects an optimal subset given the input set $O$, a lookup table or function for $f$, and the desired size $n_s$:

  $$Algorithm(O, n_s, f) \rightarrow S$$
- two of the above problems have well-known solutions that can be run easily on modern computers, whilst one has no known solution other than total enumeration, with factorial complexity.  It strikes me that

  - perhaps that some of these problems have solutions is down to special cases of this problem that are easily solved, and the question I am asking has no general solution, even if specific solutions in other problems do exist. Principal component analysis feels very similar to the situation in which I have encountered this, but the way in which the algorithm continues to select new vectors, the orthogonality, etc., may make a fundamental difference between tihs solution and the solution for the more general problem at large.
  - each problem sounds similar yet is formulated slightly differently - in this case, as we are selectig a subset, the order does not matter, which is not the case for a tree, where edges matter, or the TSP, where cycles are the issue. I may have seen similar problems before, but the precise formulation is really quite different. Again, it seems subtle to me if I'm asking about a well-known solution that I can't put a name to, or this is basically another case of TSP and it's to the best of our knowledge, impossible to solve.

## Context / Example

- The real context behind this is selecting sets of 3D vectors in space, trying to increase the variation of those included in the set, so that I get a subsample with a nice range that represents the set as a whole. But, I think the problem is much more nicely visualised, in two dimensions, as the below:

> I run a travel company and I am going to create a map for my website to show off the variety of destinations that customers can visit with my company.
> I fly to every single international airport in the world (or you can just as well use capital cities if you want), so my original set is all of the international airports in the world.
>
> I can only show 16 pins on the map to display on my website whilst keeping it legible by guests.
>
> So, my problem is, how can I select a subset, with a fixed size, from my input set, that maximises the sum of the distance between each element of this subset with every other. That is, how can I pick as diverse a range of destinations around the world as possible, and feature these on my map, so that they cover a broad range of the globe, like the infographic below:
> [Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WSFA.jpg)

We will simplify this and pretend the Earth lies on a rectangular map - the distance between two airports on the globe is now modelled as the Euclidean distance between their 2D co-ordinates on a map.

### First Solution

The original solution I came up with was trivial to implement:

- Create a triangular matrix/array, putting every international airport in the world in the row and column "headings". Each entry in the matrix/array contains the distance between the airport for its row, and the airport for its column.
- Now we can reshape this matrix to a list, and sort it. Extracting the top 8 entries will result in the pairs of airports that are maximally distant from each other. My code will handle the complication that we might select the same airport twice so we can neglect this for the time bieng.  The problem we now have is that whilst we have extracted the elements with the greatest total distance from the original set, our results may not be ideal:

### Issues with this

The algorithm may well see that Tokyo and Santiago are a long way away. So are Beijing and Vancouver, Seoul and Los Angeles, Hanoi and Guadalajara. It's likely that globally, the pairings of cities that cover the greatest distance will select a number of cities in the Far East matched with cities in the western Americas. So now, we have a map with individual pairs of cities that are very distant from their partners, but located quite close to other cities in our subset. Even if (London and Warsaw), (Bilbao and St Petersburg), (Abuja and Luanda) aren't nearly as far from each other as (Tokyo and Santiago), as a subset these six cover a greater spread of the world than our original set, which is tending towards the edges of our map.

We'll take it as a given that whatever metric we use between each pair of elements in our sets, this is easily calculable and the time complexity of $f$ is negligible - if we say there are to the order 1000 intrnational airports in the world, it is going to take very little time for a modern computer to fill a matrix with the distance between every possible pair of airports and this can be done in advance.

So our algorithm comes down to the selection process of our ouput set - we take it that whatever the complexity of the arbitrary metric between any two elements, because our input is a finite set, we can compute all of this beforehand, and just look up the metric for a given pair of items in constant time in order to build our set.

## Outstanding Problems

Using the above method, I think it's correct to say that we have selected the set with the maximal total metric from $f$ of our original input set - if we want $n_s$ items then we can't select any better *pairings* from the original set in terms of that metric. But then, once we have composed our subset, the sum of the metric values between each and every item of our subset could potentially be improved.

I also realise I may have misformulated the generic problem in the question from the example at hand (the map problem).

Let's say we wanted a subset of size three, then {Adelaide, Manila, and Kuala Lumpur} would be a better subset than {Johannesburg, Edinburgh and Glasgow}, even though that subset has a smaller total value of $f$:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Edinburgh | Glasgow | 67 |
| Edinburgh | Johannesburg | 9601 |
| Johannesburg | Glasgow | 9624 |
|  | Total | 19292 |

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adelaide | Kuala Lumpur | 5720 |
| Adelaide | Manila | 5822 |
| Manila | Kuala Lumpur | 2465 |
|  | Total | 14007 |
|  |  |  |

In this case perhaps I have not been correct at all in specifying my problem as how to select the subset with maximal total $f$, or it may be that I would need to rethink how I define my function $f$. Quite possible also that my maths is just totally off altogether.

##### Thanks for any help on this! Please do let me know if I need to redefine my problem, I'm not so confident I have done so accurately.

Comment: If $f$ is generic, this is an NP-hard problem.